# Getting mailbox statistics (resultsItemSize) from a soft-deleted mailbox over N years

Tags: powershell

For auditing purposes we're doing a whatif scenario to analyse whether decreasing the length we store a mailbox for will impact the amount of data that is stored on an account that are currently in our litigation hold (soft-deleted mailboxes). In order to do that, I need to access the mailboxes using the search-mailboxes function. I am able to do this on existing mailboxes (as shown in the code below) but the same code (and variations of the paramaters) don't seem to make a difference.

An example on an existing mailbox. I am interested in the resultItemSize. I have comfirmed with the user that this is moderately accurate.

```
WARNING: Search-Mailbox is being dep
recated. Please use New-ComplianceSearch and related eDiscovery commands instead.
WARNING: The Search-Mailbox cmdlet returns up to 10000 results per mailbox if a search query is specified. To return more than 10000 results, use the New-MailboxSearch cmdlet or the 
In-Place eDiscovery & Hold console in the Exchange Administration Center.
```

Output from console. This is the input I want.

```
Identity         : Foo
TargetMailbox    : 
Success          : True
TargetFolder     : 
ResultItemsCount : 3471
ResultItemsSize  : 224.1 MB (235,013,064 bytes)
```

When attempting on a non-active user account. Note the litigation hold users have been confirmed to be in our system and I've taken a subset of them and stored them in a separate CSV. Currently, i'm running a forloop.

```
 $value = Get-Mailbox -identity $i.Alias -InactiveMailboxOnly | search-mailbox -SearchQuery "received<=$((get-date).addyears(-1).toString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"))" -IncludeUnsearchableItems -Verbose
```

Output from console:

```
The target mailbox or .pst file path is required.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=VI1P180MB0000,RequestId=8535af1d-a9ce-48a8-ab5f-Abcdef,TimeStamp=23/09/2019 07:10:17] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ArgumentException] 4B34FFB 
   E
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

I ran the two values separately to see where the error flags up which occurs at the search-mailbox size. If anyone has overcome this particular issue, I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: In your search query, specifically the `ToString` bit there is a "Z" at the end? Is this supposed to be here as it may be messing with your search. I get `2018-09-23T08:54:10Z` when I run your Get-Date command `(get-date).addyears(-1).toString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")`

Comment: Yep it's a typo and I have changed it! (thanks!)  but it doesn't solve the problem. I still run it within the code for the existing user, but outputs the same value.

Comment: So for some reason I didn't pick up on the T inbetween the day and hours bit as well, try `(get-date).addyears(-1).toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` - this displays the date / time as expected on my end and at least we can then rule that out as being an issue

Answer (score 1):

To those in the future looking for the answer, the solution:

```
$user = $i.Alias

$value = Get-Mailbox -identity $user -InactiveMailboxOnly | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery "received <= $((get-date).AddYears(-7).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")) AND sent <= $((get-date).AddYears(-7).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))" -EstimateResultOnly
```